# Xpath with multiple descendant conditions

Tags: xpath

I have an HTML file that looks like:

```
<div id="products">
   <div class="product">
      <span class="productheader">Product 1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
   </div>
   <div class="product">
      <span class="productheader">Product 2</span>
      <div class="selected_value and_other value plus one value">
         <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="product">
      <span class="productheader">Product 3</span>
      <span class="hidden">
         <div class="selected_value and_other value">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have the value from *header* where:

- the *input* is "checked" --> div class from descendant contains "selected_value"
- but not hidden --> the selected is not part of span with class "hidden"

so, only the second *productheader* value (Product 2) should be the result.

How should the correct xpath look like?

Tried many things, but none works. Most closely:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'product')]//*[descendant::div[contains(@class ,"selected_value")]]
```

Problem is that this does not account that it may not be hidden!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways as shown below.
Option 1:

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'selected_value')][not(parent::span[@class='hidden'])]/preceding-sibling::span/text()
```

Option 2: simplest

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'selected_value')]/preceding-sibling::span/text()
```

Option 3: If you want to use the span class then follow this.

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'selected_value')]/preceding-sibling::span[@class='productheader']/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete @supputuri's answer, more (5) XPath options (from shortest to longest):

```
//input[@checked][not(ancestor::span)]/preceding::span[1]/text()
//div[@class="product"][.//@checked and not(span[@class="hidden"])]/*[1]/text()
//input[@checked][not(ancestor::span)]/ancestor::div[@class="product"]/*[1]/text()
//input[@checked][not(ancestor::span)]/ancestor::div[@class="product"]/*[1]/text()
//span[@class="productheader"][following::input[1][@checked][not(ancestor::span)]]/text()
```